# Reading 4 bytes with struct.unpack

Tags: python, struct

I have a file whose bytes #11-15 hold an integer that is 4 bytes long. Using `struct.unpack`, I want to read it as a 4-byte integer. Right now, with PACK_FORMAT set to `8s2s4B2s16B96s40B40B`, I read 4 separate bytes:

```
PACK_FORMAT = '8s2s4B2s16B96s40B40B'
fd = open('./myfile', 'r')
hdrBytes = fd.read(208)
print(repr(hdrBytes))

foo = struct.unpack(PACK_FORMAT, hdrBytes)

(Pdb) foo[0]
'MAGICSTR'
(Pdb) foo[1]
'01'
(Pdb) foo[2:6]
(48, 50, 48, 48)
(Pdb) print repr(hdrBytes)
'MAGICSTR010200a0000000001e100010........`
```

Now I can convert these 4 bytes to an int as:

```
(Pdb) int(''.join([chr(x) for x in foo[2:6]]), 16)
512
```

When I modified `PACK_FORMAT` to use using `i` instead of `4B` to read 4 bytes, but always get an error:

```
foo = struct.unpack(PACK_FORMAT, hdrBytes)
error: unpack requires a string argument of length 210
```

Comment: The ordering of format characters may have an impact on size since the padding needed to satisfy alignment requirements is different:

>>> pack('ci', '*', 0x12131415)
'*\x00\x00\x00\x12\x13\x14\x15'
>>> pack('ic', 0x12131415, '*')
'\x12\x13\x14\x15*'
>>> calcsize('ci')
8
>>> calcsize('ic')
5

Comment: This is right from the manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with alignment — see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment).

```
import struct

PACK_FORMAT1 = '8s 2s 4B 2s 16B 96s 40B 40B'
print(struct.Struct(PACK_FORMAT1).size)  # -> 208

PACK_FORMAT2 = '8s 2s i 2s 16B 96s 40B 40B'
print(struct.Struct(PACK_FORMAT2).size)  # -> 210

PACK_FORMAT3 = '=8s 2s i 2s 16B 96s 40B 40B'
print(struct.Struct(PACK_FORMAT3).size)  # -> 208
```

Comment: If I use `=`, I get an absurd value for the integer:
`
(Pdb)PACK_FORMAT 
'=8s2si2s16B96s40B40B'

(Pdb) foo
('MAGICSTR', '01', 808464944, 'a0',.....)` Trying to understand why this happens?

Comment: Sounds like it could be a byte order issue, try using `>` and `<` instead of `=` and see which one gives reasonable looking results (or look at the raw data and figure it yourself).

Comment: P.S. Most binary formats specify whether the data in them is in big or little-endian format (or have a flag somewhere in a header that says indicates which is being used).

Comment: Hexdump from my file is below. The 4 bytes I want to read and upack are 0200
`0000000   M   A   G   I   C   S   T   R   0   1   0   2   0   0   a   0`
`0000010   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   e   1   0   0   0   1   0`

Comment: If the `0200` is supposed to represent 512 decimal, then it looks like the value is in big-endian format, so try using `>` instead of `=`. The latter means whatever is native to your computer which obviously can be different than the data in the file.

Comment: `(Pdb) PACK_FORMAT
'>8s2si2s16B96s40B40B'`

`(Pdb) foo
('MAGICSTR', '01', 808595504, ........)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99977/discussion-between-linuxfan-and-martineau).

Comment: I figured-out the problem, the 0200 is an ASCII string not binary data. `808595504` decimal is `0x30323030` in binary which is `"0200"` if interpreted as string — so what you want is `4c` in the format string and you'd need to convert that to a decimal number manually with `int(foo[2])`.

Comment: You're welcome. On further reflection, _all_ your data appears to be in string format, so you'll need to revise your entire format string accordingly (using `c` format characters for each substring) and then convert those representing decimal or hex numbers accordingly — `int()` can convert both types of numbers from strings if you specify a base. ie `int(foo[2], 16)`

Comment: Perfect. I'll also check why the file-format has ascii instead of bytes for all fields.

Comment: Good idea since sending binary data as ASCII hexadecimal digits is doubling the size of the file.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're running afoul of the alignment requirement: integers must be on a 4-byte boundary on your machine.

You can turn off alignment by starting your format string with an equals sign:

PACK_FORMAT = '=8s2si2s16B96s40B40B'